# Trouble getting started with Lua

Tags: lua

I wanted to learn Lua so I bought a book.  The problem I'm having is finding a compiler/interpreter.  I downloaded the binary compiler for Windows from http://luadist.org/ (Windows x86 (MinGW32 4.7.1)).  But every time I try to start it up I just says:

> The program can't start because lua53.dll is missing from your
>   computer.  Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

Which I did several times to no avail.  I've tried to find another compiler but this seems to be the only one... which I find hard to believe.  There are "demo" compilers but I want one I can install so I can do the examples in the book.  There are instructions on how to "compile" the compiler at the Lua site on Linux and Mac machines but I'm working on a Windows machine.

Any help?

Comment: How are you running the interpreter? (`lua.exe`)

Comment: You should have `lua53.exe` and `lua53.dll` in the same folder

Comment: There are many pre-compiled versions on the Net for either Windows or Linux.  For Windows, I use this one: http://www.aspisys.com/lua.exe which is a single executable (no DLL dependencies) and also includes SQLite3 with the (l)sqlite3 module, and the lfs module.  BTW, the same is also available for Linux (the same link but without the .exe extension).

Comment: I realize this isn't quite the kind of answer you are asking for but Lua is highly portable C. If you can use C at all, it is very simple to create lua.exe: 1) Compile all *.c except luac.c. 2) Link all object files to lua.exe. Conversely, to create luac.exe. (Or, install [mingw32-base via mingw-get-setup.exe](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/Installer/mingw-get/) and `make mingw`. Instead, use [Visual C++](http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools)) if you like.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ZeroBrane Studio is the best for Lua.  It works on Windows, Mac, and Linux.  It was specifically designed for beginners, but it a full featured IDE for writing and debugging Lua code.

https://studio.zerobrane.com/

Be sure to try the "Run as Scratchpad" feature which provides a "live-coding" experience.